# How to convert a python expression to android?

Tags: java, python, image-processing, android, opencv

I am developing an android application which is already made in pyhon using OpenCv.
I am currently trying to detect and extract objects from an image in java.
How can I convert thi line of code written in python to java ?

```
    miniature=gray[y:y+D,x:x+2*d/7]
```

gray and miniature are both Mat objects.

I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: What does this code do in python?

Comment: It extract from gray Mat a new Mat called miniature

Comment: What else code do you have in java? In python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are simply trying to extract a sub matrix from a matrix - i.e. in your example the y:y+d means from index y to index y + d.

Java has as similar method to get sub matrices(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#submat-org.opencv.core.Range-org.opencv.core.Range-)):

```js
public Mat submat(int rowStart,
                  int rowEnd,
                  int colStart,
                  int colEnd)
```